# Question regarding the object getting serilaized in Django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here I'm with a simple doubt where I'm completely confused. I have Model called `ReviewsRatings` to shows reviews based on each product.And created a Model Serializer `ReviewSerilaizer`. In views, am passing this `ReviewsRatings` instance to `ReviewSerilaizer`

```
class ShowReviews(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product_slug = self.kwargs["product_slug"]
        reviews = ReviewRatings.objects.filter(user=request.user, product__slug=product_slug)
        if not reviews:
            return Response([])
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True, context={'request':request})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

#Serializer

```
class ReviewSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = SerializerMethodField()
 
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewRatings
        fields = [
            "user",
            "rating",
            "review",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
      
        ]

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.user.first_name} {obj.user.last_name}"
```

So my doubt is in `def get_user(self, obj)` the `obj` is the `product object` which am getting. And in the views I,m filtering `user = request.user` along with `product__slug=product_slug`. So why Im not getting `user object` instead getting `Products object`

Here is the Models.

```
class ReviewRatings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    review = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Reviews & Ratings"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_name
```

I don't know it's a dumb question to be asked or I didn't asked the question correctly. But this is making me so confused.

Comment: serializer calls get_user method in order to get the value for "user" field. This method is passed the "Review" instance. And so, obj.user resolves to the related user instance (user who left the review, I suppose). Docs for method field - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: User in the modal & serializerMetodField have same spelling, try changing the spelling, I guess it may work

Comment: @EugenePrikazchikov Hey I'm asking why Im getting Product object instead of User object.